# Promise Resolve inside Traverse npm

Tags: node.js, promise, es6-promise, traversal

**Concept:**
I want my MongoDB document to be updated with new encryption. for this I am using traverse library npm which iterate over Every object key: pair now problem arises when is mark Traverse(Object).each(async(__data) <-- if is use async-await Than traverse will start skipping data return from __data.i also tried BlueBird for promise. resolve but it splitted all data into individual character set.

**Question**
I want async functionality inside traverse.each method so that any data change happen inside traverse will be asyncronus.

**Code**

```
// if given @_dataType is not empty.
    await FindAndReplace(_dataPipe).forEach((data) => {
      // local variable.
      let _hash

      console.log('13-043')
      console.log(TypeCheck('Object', data) && _.keys(data).indexOf(_allowedHash[m]) > -1, data, _allowedHash[m])
      // if current key is allowed.
      if (TypeCheck('Object', data) && _.keys(data).indexOf(_allowedHash[m]) > -1) {
        // Argon2 data.
        BlueBird.method(__Argon2.hash([data[_allowedHash[m]]]), __hash => {
          // concat hash result.
          _hash += __hash
        })

        console.log('-1304')
        console.log(_hash, TypeCheck('String', _hash), data[_allowedHash[m]])
        // on successful data encoding.
        if (TypeCheck('String', _hash)) {
          data[_allowedHash[m]] = _hash
          data['encryption'] = {
            'Argon2': {
              'for': _allowedHash[m],
              'hash': _hash
            }
          }

          // emmit data for allowing validation.
          _emmit('Argon2', Argon2)

          // style guide.
          Context.debug(`data encoded successfully with argon2..`, 'successful')
        }
      }
    })
```

**NOTE**
if I am not clean Than let me know what else I can provide you. so that you call tell me exaclty why it is not working. and how will it work?

**Thanks**

Comment: Where is that `Traverse(Object).each(` that you mention in the code you posted? Also can you please link its documentation?

Comment: [You cannot use Array `forEach` with promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37576787/1048572), and probably the same holds for any custom `each` function, unless it explicitly supports asynchronous callbacks.